# How to connect to aws elactic redis cache in .net using a single url which may connect to primary or secondary node based on availability?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, caching, redis

How to connect to Redis using single URL that may route to primary or secondary node based on availability in .NET?
I have tried stack exchange Redis, and I have idea that we can setup route53 in front of global data store which will redirect to Redis URLs to connect either primary or secondary node to connect to base on availability. But I don't know if it's possible to use Route53 URL in .NET Redis configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use configuration end point of the cluster.

You can find the Redis (cluster mode enabled) cluster's endpoint from AWS Management console.

Comment: but how do i make redis to connect to secondary cluster if primary fails in? FYI, i am using stackexchangeredis.extensions.core library in .net.